# mySql search "sub.domain.com" from "domain.com"

Tags: php, mysql, email, where-clause, email-validation

**Summery:**

In MySql table Rows are

- domain.com
- domain.net
- stackoverflow.com

I want to search "sub.domain.com" from table... How??

---

**Detail:**
Hi, I am working on email validation script,

I have a list of blacklist domains in array...
Now i want to move to database...

But some logically issue..

**Previous code, with array**

```
$blacklist_domains  = array("domain.com","domain.net");
    foreach($blacklist_domains as $val) {
        //$domain can be with or without sub domain
        if( preg_match( "/$val/", $domain)){
               return true;
        }
    }
```

here working is, i have domain list,
but when i want to search domain, it may be domain/sub domain (My Theoretically, but this theory still not true)
So this loop searching blacklist in domain

```
foreach($blacklist_domains as $val) {
  //$domain can be with or without sub domain
  if( preg_match( "/$val/", $domain)){
         return true;
  }
}

**run time concept:**

//preg_match( "/blacklist/", "find this");
if( preg_match( "/domain.com/", "sub.domain.com")){
    return true;
}
```

**Question:**
Now, i want to move this concept to database...
in database my rows are,

- domain.com
- domain.net

now i want to search sub.domain.com in table

How OR any better idea?

> My aim is, to just check email blacklist domain from my blacklist domain
>   list in database

**Thank you**

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Ok i will search, Kindly tell me, Keywords, what i search in google? what the name of this thing? that i am talking about? i guess its not a where clouse like query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have had `sub.domain.com` in your database and were searching for `domain.com`, you would have used `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain LIKE '%domain.com%';
```

**But you don't**

That means, you need a "reversed" `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE 'sub.domain.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain, '%');
```

To make your code more efficient, you can even use `COUNT()` to get the number of rows to directly use in your code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM domains WHERE 'sub.domain.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain, '%');
```

Comment: Thank you,, You give me my answer, But i dont know why some one give you negative marks... !!!